# Multiplication Table program won't work

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a program that uses functions or a function to find the multiplications of a number (which the user has to pick) from one to twelve. For instance; the 'two times' tables: `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc.`

My current code is:

```
def findthetable(multi):
    table = tablechoice
    table = int()
    one = table * 1
    two = table * 2
    three = table * 3
    four = table * 4
    five = table * 5
    six = table * 6
    seven = table * 7
    eight = table * 8
    nine = table * 9
    ten = table * 10
    eleven = table * 11
    twelve = table * 12

    multi = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve]
    print(multi)

    return multi

tablechoice = int(input("Please enter a number that you would like to find the times tables for: ")
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the first 2 lines in your function? Remove them, use `table` instead of `multi` as parameter name and try again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to be able to help you, we need to know what you're inputting to your program, what it is returning, and what you **expected** it to return. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have to call `findthetable(tablechoice)` after you input the value. You should be using `multi` instead of `table` because that's where your value is coming form.

Comment: Also, consider using a `for` loop.

Comment: Kurt, why is my value coming from multi? I thought I set multi to be my list for printing out each of the numbers after they were multiplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways I can think of.

**1) List comprehension**

```
>> n = int(input("Please enter a number to find the times tables:"))
>> ["{0} X {1} => {2}".format(n, i, n*i) for i in range(1,13)]

['2 X 1 => 2', '2 X 2 => 4', '2 X 3 => 6', '2 X 4 => 8', '2 X 5 => 10', '2 X 6 => 12', '2 X 7 => 14', '2 X 8 => 16', '2 X 9 => 18', '2 X 10 => 20', '2 X 11 => 22', '2 X 12 => 24']
```

wrapped around a function it should look like this:

```
def multiTable(n)
    tableList = ["{0} X {1} => {2}".format(n, i, n*i) for i in range(1,13)]
    for _ in tableList:
        print(_)

>> n = int(input("Please enter a number to find the times tables:"))
## Assuming n = 2
>> multiTable(n)

2 X 1 => 2
2 X 2 => 4
2 X 3 => 6
2 X 4 => 8
2 X 5 => 10
2 X 6 => 12
2 X 7 => 14
2 X 8 => 16
2 X 9 => 18
2 X 10 => 20
2 X 11 => 22
2 X 12 => 24
```

**2) Yield**

```
def multiTable(n)
    for _ in range(1, 13):
        yield n*_

>> n = int(input("Please enter a number to find the times tables:"))
## Assuming n = 2
>> for i in multiTable(n): print(i)
 2
 4
 6
 8
 10
 12
 14
 16
 18
 20
 22
 24
```

I know this one is a useless example for demonstrating the power of `yield`; still good for learning.

And finally, **your code** modified:

```
def findthetable(multi):
    # table = tablechoice
    # table = int()
    table = int(multi)
    one = table * 1
    two = table * 2
    three = table * 3
    four = table * 4
    five = table * 5
    six = table * 6
    seven = table * 7
    eight = table * 8
    nine = table * 9
    ten = table * 10
    eleven = table * 11
    twelve = table * 12

    multi = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve]
    print(multi)

    return multi

>>> tablechoice = input("Please enter a number that you would like to find the times tables for: ")
>>> findthetable(tablechoice)
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
```

Comment: I have to use skills that we've learnt in class and I can't exactly use these as they look a bit ahead of my skill range for my knowledge of Python.

Comment: What I'm trying to get is my code edited so that it works.

Comment: Hey @BlizzardGizzard, I've modified your code for it to work. But , do take out time to understand the other two examples. Finally, if you think that this answers this question, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate you taking your time to respond. =)

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one answer. Define the function named findthetable. The first input parameter is the the number of "times" you want to use, and the second input parameter is the range of numbers you want to pick up from. For example, if you plan to find out all 2 times table from `1,2,3,...,12`, just call `findthetable(2, 12)`

```
def findthetable(num_times, num_range): 
    result = [ num_times* i for i in range(1, num_range//num_times + 1) ]
    return result

print (findthetable(2, 12))
```

Comment: Surely this would now only do the two times tables?

Comment: no, the first input parameter is the number of 'times'. if you want to get 3 times table in [1, 12], call findthetable(3, 12)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made my multiplication table recently:

```
def MulTable():
n=int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
for row in range(1,n+1):
    print(*("{:3}".format(row*col) for col in range(1, n+1)))
```

`MulTable()`